# what is ram console area in kernel RAM ?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want to know what is ram console buffer ?? is it same buffer which is reserved at kernel bootup time and here last kernel last logs are store ??
 if so can anybody tell where is in code it's doing so ??

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ram-console is reserved area in RAM ,which reserved at boot-up time.
This area is  of persistent property.This is used to store last kernel log messages.
In case kernel reboot or crashes, Logs stored here can be useful for kernel crash debugging
by  knowing what really was happing just before crash or reboot.